# Entity Framework custom ModelBuilder failing to be created properly when using the DbContextOptionsBuilder UseModel method

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, entity, dbcontext

I have a database context that I want to separate some logic from the OnModelCreating method in another file instead.

My current onModelCreating method in AppDbContext looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(GetType().Assembly);
// modelBuilder.Seed();

if (Database.IsSqlite())
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        IgnoreNullValues = true, IncludeFields = true
    };
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
        .Property(e => e.Profile)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, options), 
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TenantProfile>(v, options)!
        );
}
```

It works completely fine and checks if the database is an sqlite db, then I add some extra logic to support jsonb column serialization/deserialization since my original database is using postgres.

My unit tests use a Sqlite inmemory connection. I want to separate this code into a separate file so i created a TestWithSqlite.cs file that contains this custom model that I used the DbContextOptionsBuilder UseModel method to configure:

```
//Create sqlite db model
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder(new ConventionSet());
modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(AppDbContext).Assembly);
var jsonoptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { IgnoreNullValues = true, IncludeFields = true };
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>()
    .Property(e => e.Profile)
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, jsonoptions), 
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TenantProfile>(v, jsonoptions)!
    );

var model = modelBuilder.Model.FinalizeModel();

var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
    .UseModel(model)
    .UseSqlite(_connection)
    .Options;
AppDbContext = new AppDbContext(options, mediatorMock.Object, _auditContext);
AppDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

However, when I run my unit tests now i get the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIp4o.png)

> "The property 'AppUser.AvatarImage' could not be mapped because it is
> of type 'string', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid
> entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using
> the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'."

String properties are however primitive types and i'm assuming I have not configured the custom model properly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: The error seems to occur when the unit tests hit the `AppDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` method

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be I was using a `modelBuilder` with an empty `ConventionSet`. This `modelBuilder` had no idea how to map my data properly.
To fix this, I instantiated the `modelBuilder` with my database providers custom `ConventionSetBuilder` provided by the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MetaData.Conventions` namespace.

```
ModelBuilder modelBuilder = SqliteConventionSetBuilder.CreateModelBuilder();
```